# How do I count specific values across multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA':['?',2,3,4,'?'],
    'colB':[1,2,'?',3,4],
    'colC':['?',2,3,4,5]
})
```

I would like to get the count the the number of `'?'` in each column and return the following output -

```
colA - 2
colB - 1
colC - 1
```

Is there a way to return this output at once. Right now the only way I know how to do it is write a for loop for each column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

looks like the simple way is

`df[df == '?'].count()`

the result is

```
colA    2
colB    1
colC    1
dtype: int64
```

where `df[df == '?']` give us DataFrame with `?` and `Nan`

```
  colA colB colC
0    ?  NaN    ?
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    ?  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4    ?  NaN  NaN
```

and the [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) non-NA cells for each column.

Please, look on the other solutions: [good readable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103323/8060120) and the [most faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103435/8060120)

Comment: Nice solution. Just wonder what'll be the best way to print all rows/columns where '?' exist? (omitting all the NaN ones)

Comment: I tried add the dropna but it works slowly on my laptop, or what you mean?

Comment: dropna() is definitely an option, but it will drop any row/column that contains any NaN and you won't get any response in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) here.

```
pd.Series(np.count_nonzero(df.to_numpy()=='?', axis=0), index=df.columns)
# pd.Series((df.values == '?').sum(0), index=df.columns)

colA    2
colB    1
colC    1
dtype: int64
```

Timeit results:

Benchmarking with `df` of shape `(1_000_000, 3)`

```
big_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().repeat(200_000,axis=0))
big_df.shape
(1000000, 3)
```

---

```
In [186]: %timeit pd.Series(np.count_nonzero(big_df.to_numpy()=='?', axis=0), index=big_df.columns)
53.1 ms ± 231 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [187]: %timeit big_df.eq('?').sum()
171 ms ± 7.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [188]: %timeit big_df[big_df == '?'].count()
314 ms ± 4.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [189]: %timeit pd.Series(np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: Counter(x)['?'], 0, big_df.values), index=big_df.columns)
174 ms ± 3.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: great solution on my machine it is the faster way of all

Answer (score 2):

We can do `sum`

```
df.eq('?').sum()
Out[182]: 
colA    2
colB    1
colC    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bear Brown Answer is probably the most elegant, a faster option is to use numpy:

```
from collections import Counter    

%%timeit
df[df == '?'].count()

5.2 ms ± 646 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
pd.Series(np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: Counter(x)['?'], 0, df.values), index=df.columns)

218 µs ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation to BENY's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103323/7254755):

```
(df=='?').sum()
Out[182]: 
colA    2
colB    1
colC    1
dtype: int64
```