# Looping over a section of data and suming in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly large dataset, I would like to sum values equal to 1 for every row.

input file:

```
1526  0 1 2 1 0
782   0 1 1 1 2
7653  1 1 1 0 0
87bt  1 0 1 2 2
```

desired output file:

```
1526 2
782 3
7653 3
87bt 2
```

my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data1', delimiter=' ')

 df_sub = df.iloc[:,1:]

sum1=0

for het in df_sub:

     if het==1 :

      sum1=sum1+1
 print(sum1)
```

Comment: You don't have column names? And can you explain your logic.

Comment: yes no column names. I would like print or write to a file the first column values and their corresponding sums of "1"

Comment: avoid python looping with large datasets ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/6692898

Comment: @Ch3steR honestly I dont like the implicit use of `axis=1` with just `sum(1)`, it's so confusing syntax, especially in your example. In the first part it means literally the integer 1, while in the second part its the axis argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) here. I suggest using `index_col` parameter in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to set index while reading the csv itself.

```
from io import StringIO
text = '''1526  0 1 2 1 0
782   0 1 1 1 2
7653  1 1 1 0 0
87bt  1 0 1 2 2'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), header=None, index_col=0) #`index_col=0` sets 1st column as index
df.eq(1).sum(axis=1)
0
1526    2
782     3
7653    3
87bt    2
dtype: int64
```

You can use [`np.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) if performance is an issue, it's significantly faster than `df.eq(...).sum(...)`, timeit results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103435/12416453)

```
np.count_nonzero(df.to_numpy()==1, axis=1)
# array([2, 3, 3, 2], dtype=int64)
# pd.Series(np.count_nonzero(df.to_numpy()==1, axis=1), index=df.index)
# This is almost 3X faster than `df.eq(...).sum(...)`
# For more details refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103435/12416453
```

`axis=1` means "over the column axis", pandas would also accept:

```
df.eq(1).sum(axis='columns')
```

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("data1", header=None, index_col=0,delimiter=' ')
a = pd.Series(np.count_nonzero(df.to_numpy()==1, axis=1), index=df.index)
this prints just 0s for all rows